# Python: smallest denormalized double error

Tags: python, double, denormalized

Using WinPython 3.4.4.2, I get the following weird result:

```
>>> 2**-1075
5e-324
```

That is, the same as `2**-1074`, whereas `2**-1075` should be zero in double float representation. With Python 3.5.1 at the address https://www.python.org/shell/, I get 0 as expected.

May anybody help me to understand what's going wrong?

Thank you

Comment: I can't duplicate your result Python 3.4.3 (default, Oct 14 2015, 20:28:29) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 2**-1075
0.0
>>>

Comment: Have you done anything that might screw with floating-point rounding modes? What happens if you try even lower exponents?

Comment: I didn't do anything, just installed WinPython and immediatly did such tests. I gt the right 0.0 for lower exponents: only this one gives a wrong answer!

Answer (score 1):

The smallest re-presentable denormalized floats larger, and smaller, than zero are: **5e-324** and **-5e-324**.

**5e-324** is the denormalized minimum which can be achieved by multiplying minimum floating point number(2.2250738585072014e-308) with floating point epsilon(2.220446049250313e-16).

```
import sys
print(sys.float_info.min*sys.float_info.epsilon)
```

**Output:**

```
5e-324
```

I also get the same result in my shell (Python 3.5.1). The address https://www.python.org/shell/ uses console from http://www.pythonanywhere.com/ which might control such operation in their system.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

2**-1074 is the smallest subnormal float.  2**-1075 ought to be 0.0, but on Windows, thanks to the behavior of the C pow() function, it is not.  Interestingly, 2**-1074 / 2 will give 0.0.  And math.ldexp(1, -1075) will also give 0.0.